# Yii2 console Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When I enter command `yii` or `test/codeception/bin/yii migrate` in the console, receive such a message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\console\ErrorHandler::errorAction' in D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:197
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(518): yii\base\Component->__set('errorAction', 'site/error')
#1 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\ErrorHandler), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\console\\Err...', Array, Array)
#5 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\console\\Err...', Array, Array)
#6 D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(13 in D:\Desktop\loalhost\yii2-wiersz\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php on line 197
```

console/config/main.php is default. Problem is on localhost (win7x62) and remote host (debian).
I had the same situation with the attempt to migrate rbac
(yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations)

What is causing the problem ??? my ignorance ;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you error message says, you are trying to set unknown property 'errorAction'. I suppose you are using the same error component config here in console app as in web app. See if there is

```
[
    'components' => [
        'error' => [
            'errorAction' => ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

in your console app config. There shouldn't be 'errorAction'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,
I moved from frontend/config and backend/config code

```
'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ]
```

to common/config. Frontend and backend app did not have a problem with that, but  console yes. After rollback is ok.